# How to dynamically bind to object property inside component?

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, vue-component

I am trying to make a Vue.js check list component:

It will be used like this:

```
<check-list :items="myItems" text-property="name" />
```

Definition:

```
<template>
  <div class="form-control item-container">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mr-sm-2" v-for="item in items" :key="item.value">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" :id="item.value">
      <label class="custom-control-label" :for="item.value">{{item[item.textProperty]}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I do not want to hard code the `text` property. How do I pass in the property name to use as a parameter then dynamically bind to that in the template?

This `{{item[item.textProperty]}}` should ideally auto bind to `item['name']` in my example above.

I would like to avoid use of javascript.

Comment: It should be `{{ item[textProperty] }}`

Comment: @fabruex perfect thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
{{ item[textProperty] }}
```

without `item` in the name of the property